# Php Form connect to mySql

Tags: mysql

I have CREATE TABLE query, INSERT INTO which auto display "expiry_date" column, and FORM on my website. I am a newbie so I don't know how to make the form, especially "expiry_date" field to send data to my database.
Please tell me how to connect "Expiry_date" form field to SQL QUERY. I have 3 parts to show you what I've already done.

**1st part**

#### SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `expirydate_table` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `firstname` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
    `lastname` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
    `email` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
    `password` VARCHAR( 12 ) NOT NULL ,
    `signup_date` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
    `expiry_date` DATE NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
    UNIQUE (
    `email`
    )
    ) TYPE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE 

    utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**2nd part**

```
INSERT INTO `expirydate_table` ( `id` , `firstname` , `lastname` , `email` , `password` , `signup_date` , `expiry_date` ) 
VALUES (
'', 'pp', 'wiraj', 'pp@hotmail.com', 'test2009', NOW( ) , DATE_ADD(CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 30 DAY ))
```

**3rd part**

```
<form method="post" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
<table align="center">
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Firstname:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Lastname:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lastname" value="" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Password:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password" value="" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Signup_date:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="signup_date" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">Expiry_date:</td>
    <td><input name="expiry_date" type="text" size="32"></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr valign="baseline">
    <td nowrap align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking about executing query submitted from a form?If so you should use

[PHP](http://php.net/)

You can access the post data with $_POST['nameofform'] as in where 'nameofform' is the name of your form
And you should use the php's extension to execute mysql queries [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or PDO extension

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can probably deal with your dates in code rather then send them from client. And most importantly you don't want to change `signup_date` on every UPDATE. So you need to tweak your table schema a bit:

```
CREATE TABLE `expirydate_table` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `firstname` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
    `lastname` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
    `email` VARCHAR( 45 ) NOT NULL ,
    `password` VARCHAR( 12 ) NOT NULL ,
    `signup_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `expiry_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
    UNIQUE (`email`)
)
```

That being said you can get rid of `signup_up` and `expiry_date` fields in your form.

Then you need to create an action php script that will deal with submitted values. 
It may look something like this:

```
<?php
//make sure that everything has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['firstname']) &&
    isset($_POST['lastname']) &&
    isset($_POST['email']) &&
    isset($_POST['password'])) {

    //do your cleanup and checks here
    $firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = trim($_POST['lastname']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //construct an INSERT statement
    $qry = 'INSERT INTO `expirydate_table` (`firstname` , `lastname` , `email` , `password` , `signup_date` , `expiry_date` ) VALUES ('; 

    $qry .= '"' . $firstname . '", ';
    $qry .= '"' . $lastname . '", ';
    $qry .= '"' . $email . '", ';
    $qry .= '"' . $password . '", ';
    $qry .= 'NOW(), ';
    $qry .= 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))';

    //open connection to db
    $db = new mysqli('db_host', 'db_user', 'db_pwd', 'db_name');

    //execute your INSERT statement
    if ($db->query($qry) == TRUE) {     
        if ($db->insert_id) {
            $id = $db->insert_id;
        }
    } else {
        //add your error handling here
    }

    //render your page, use $id if you need to
}
?>
```

That's definitely not everything you need to do it right.
You better, at least:

- do input validation on the client
- do proper check, validate and sanitize user input on server side
- use prepared statements
- implement proper error handling in place